# Intellij search in file causes full screen box to appear

Tags: intellij-idea

Apologies if this belongs on a different stack exchange site.

Using Intellij Ultimate v 2017.1.1 on OSX Sierra, when I do a search in file, using CMD+f, I get an unusable full screen search dialog. Has anyone seen this ? Images attached.

Before clicking CMD+f (all is well)
[image]

I try to search for something:
[image]

Any help appreciated. The Internets has so far yielded no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is already fixed, please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170295 for details.

It was caused by the Swing MigLayout misbehavior when system DPI was extremely high.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you accidentally paste a huge block of code into the finder, try CMD+f and then CMD+a and finally delete.

Comment: Thanks @jackar I thought that could be it too but deleting after selecting all didn't work. I've just installed Intellij updates and the problem has gone away, although I doubt the updates fixed an issue as much as they just reset some state